# X11VNC Timed out waiting for a response from the computer

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc, vncviewer, xvfb

My objective is to view chrome browser UI on an AWS-EC2-Ubuntu machine. I logged into AWS-Ubuntu server via my MAC Terminal, installed X11vnc on Ubuntu server and started X11vnc using the below comment:

qa_user@jins-it02:~$ x11vnc -display :1

Response received:
The VNC desktop is: jins-it02:0
PORT=5900

Then I fetched EC2 ip address 10.XXX.X.XXX, installed VNC viewer and tried connecting to Ubuntu giving the command 10.XXX.X.XXX:1.

But I am getting this error:
[image]

I tried xvnc4 and tightvnc as well but the error is the same.
Firewall in Ubuntu is inactive.
I also verified x11vnc is listening to port 5900.

What I am missing here? I read about XVFB and since my end game is to view tests running on Chrome in EC2, I installed XVFB as well. But now I am confused on how to use XVFB along side vnc. As a first step, I am trying to get x11vnc running first, view Ubuntu GUI and then get to the next step.